# Ionic collection-repeat funtion can't display in designation place

Tags: android, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I have this app built, but I can't display this collection-repeat. Everything else is working fine.

**ShowDetails.html**

```
<ion-view  view-title="Parts Listing">
  <ion-content>
  <div ng-controller="AppCtrl2">
    <ion-list>
        <ion-item collection-repeat="part in parts">
           {{ part.PartNo }} | {{ part.UpperSpecLimit}} 
        </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
    </div>
  </ion-content>
```

**controllers.js**

```
.controller('AppCtrl2', function($scope, $state, $http, $window, $filter, $timeout) {
  $scope.clicker = function(task) {
    $http.get('http://localhost:8021/testfor%20host/getDetails.php?MechNo='+ task.Machine_no)
      .success(function(result) {
        $scope.parts = result;
        alert($scope.parts);
        console.log(result);
    })
      .error(function(result) {
        console.log('data error');
      })
      .then(function(result) {
        things = result.data;
      });
    $state.go('app.ShowDetails');
  };
});
```

**JSON response from $http.get**

```
[{"PartNo": "test",
"DimentionName": "test",
"UpperSpecLimit": "9.00",
"Nominal": "5.00",
"LowerSpecLimit": "1.00",
"Actual": "1.2"},{
"PartNo": "test",
"DimentionName": "test",
"UpperSpecLimit": "9.00",
"Nominal": "5.00",
"LowerSpecLimit": "1.00",
"Actual": "12"},{
"PartNo": "test",
"DimentionName": "test",
"UpperSpecLimit": "9.00",
"Nominal": "5.00",
"LowerSpecLimit": "1.00",
"Actual": "5"}]
```

**alert($scope.parts) giving result**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems you do not fetch each object items. So, you just need to call each object items as below:

```
<ion-view  view-title="Parts Listing">
  <ion-content>
  <div ng-controller="AppCtrl2">
    <ion-list>
        <ion-item ng-repeat="part in parts">
          {{ part.PartNo }} | {{ part.UpperSpecLimit}} 
        </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
    </div>
  </ion-content>
```

Comment: ii tried ng-repeat also ready bro, this particular problem is after i use a ng-repeat in previous page with this code
`<ion-view cache-view="false" view-title="Machine List">
  <ion-content>
 <div ng-controller="AppCtrl2">
  
      <ion-list>
        <ion-item ng-repeat="item in items" 
                  item="item"
                  class="item-remove-animate" ng-click="clicker(item)">
    {{ item.Machine_no }}
        </ion-item>

      </ion-list>
 </div>
    </ion-content>
</ion-view>`


so after click a list item from this page will bring to page posted above as problem